# How can I do e2e testing if I have passwordless sign up that sends OTP to the email?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a passwordless sign up flow which uses OTP code that is sent to users email.

Here is the function that handles the sign in/sign up:

```
  // this verifies the OTP code
  const handleSignInOTP = async () => {
    toast.loading('Verifying OTP...');
    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.verifyOtp({
      email,
      token: otp,
      type: 'magiclink'
    });
    if (data) {
      toast.dismiss();
      toast.success('Successfully signed in!');
    }
    if (error) {
      toast.dismiss();
      toast.error(error.message);
    }
  };
```

At the moment I am completely lolst, how could I possibly use cypress to test something like that, is that even possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: @TomaszWojciechowski well, I want to test new user onboarding flow, but how can i bypass this sign up issue with cypress?

Comment: Are you able to get this code from e-mail by REST request? E.g. like in Mailosaur.